# Decoding JSON after sending using PHP cUrl

Tags: php, rest, json

I've researched everywhere and cannot figure this out.

I am writing a test cUrl request to test my REST service:

```
// initialize curl handler
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(
"products" => array ("product1"=>"abc","product2"=>"pass"));
$data = json_encode($data);

$postArgs = 'order=new&data=' . $data;

// set curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/store/rest.php');

// execute curl
curl_exec($ch);
```

This works fine and the request is accepted by my service and $_Post is populated as required, with two variables, order and data. Data has the encoded JSON object. And when I print out $_Post['data'] it shows:

```
{"products":{"product1":"abc","product2":"pass"}}
```

Which is exactly what is expected and identical to what was sent in.

When I try to decode this, json_decode() returns nothing!

If I create a new string and manually type that string, json_decode() works fine!

I've tried:

strip_tags() to remove any tags that might have been added in the http post
utf8_encode() to encode the string to the required utf 8
addslashes() to add slashes before the quotes

Nothing works.

Any ideas why json_decode() is not working after a string is received from an http post message?

Below is the relevant part of my processing of the request for reference:

```
public static function processRequest($requestArrays) {
    // get our verb
    $request_method = strtolower($requestArrays->server['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    $return_obj = new RestRequest();
    // we'll store our data here
    $data = array();

    switch ($request_method) {
        case 'post':
            $data = $requestArrays->post;
            break;
    }

    // store the method
    $return_obj->setMethod($request_method);

    // set the raw data, so we can access it if needed (there may be
    // other pieces to your requests)
    $return_obj->setRequestVars($data);

    if (isset($data['data'])) {
        // translate the JSON to an Object for use however you want
        //$decoded = json_decode(addslashes(utf8_encode($data['data'])));
        //print_r(addslashes($data['data']));
        //print_r($decoded);
        $return_obj->setData(json_decode($data['data']));
    }
    return $return_obj;
 }
```

Comment: This may not be the problem (hence a comment instead of an answer), but you need to `urlencode()` the JSON string before sending with cURL.  http://php.net/urlencode

Comment: I encoded the JSON string before sending it into cURL, but the result is still that same. This is driving me insane! Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: after `if (isset($data['data'])) {`, can you add a `var_dump($data['data']);` and post what it shows?

Comment: It prints out:
    string(99) "{"products":{"product1":"abc","product2":"pass"}}"

I then did the same var_dump for the JSON that is sent and it printed out:

    string(49) "{"products":{"product1":"abc","product2":"pass"}}"

If I do the same thing on the urlencode() version of the JSON object it prints out:

    string(85) "%7B%22products%22%3A%7B%22product1%22%3A%22abc%22%2C%22product2%22%3A%22pass%22%7D%7D"

Comment: I also tried preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $data); on the string that is string(99) and nothing changed.

Comment: No matter what I try to do to that string, no matter what function I hit it with (utf8_encode, decode, getval), it says its string(99). I've tried copying it to a new variable and it still behaves the same way. If I concatenate another string to it, it just adds those chars in so, if I add 2 chars it becomes string(101). I also can't access each char individually. If I search for a word I do get a position though. For example for $position = strpos($data['data', "pass"); I get 87. Do you think this a PHP bug or is there a way to clean up the string?

Comment: maybe try trimming the return value?

Comment: I've tried that already along with replacing all characters that are not alpha numeric.

Comment: `string(99) "{"products":{"product1":"abc","product2":"pass"}}"` That string is actually only 49 characters long. If this is *actually* what your PHP is outputting, something else is very very broken (or it's being interpreted by your browser and you've given us that; try looking in the document source for the actual data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that when JSON is sent by cURL inside the post parameters & quot; replaces the "as part of the message encoding. I'm not sure why the preg_replace() function I tried didn't work, but using html_entity_decode() removed the &quot and made the JSON decode-able.

Answer (score 0):

old:

```
$return_obj->setData(json_decode($data['data']));
```

new:

```
$data = json_decode( urldecode( $data['data'] ), true );
$return_obj->setData($data);
```

try it im curious if it works.